# Windows 11 complains after reboot "Why did my PC restart?"

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-preview, windows-11-upgrade

I'm installing the Windows 11 (10.0.22000.51) in a (unsupported) MacBook Pro Late 2013 using BootCamp from Apple.

I'm following this XDA article: [How to install Windows 11 on almost any unsupported PC](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-windows-11-unsupported-pc/)

I've tried to install a Windows 10 and then changed to Dev Channel using script and it didn't work well, the best options to me is:

- Burn Windows 11 to a USB ; and
- Create a hybrid installer .

In both cases, after the installation process finished and when the first reboot was finishing, I've got the message:

[image: Why did my PC restart?]

In this screen, I can access the prompt using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and then be able to run "explorer", but with limited access to the system. In this same screen, there is a "Next" button, but if I click on it, the PC restart and come back to the same screen. I cannot install the WiFi driver to be able to access internet.

I'm using a MacBook Pro Late 2013 via BootCamp, specs in [this link](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp691?locale=en_US).

The ISO was created based on "Windows 11 Insider Preview 10.0.22000.51 (co_release) amd64" from the [UUP Dump site](https://uupdump.net/selectlang.php?id=e012464d-2c1e-4c36-9051-caa99ff6f213).

**Please, could you help me to bypass this error and resume my Windows 11 instalation?**

Comment: From your link "Note: These methods can’t bypass every requirement, and your unofficial Windows 11 install may not work properly."

Comment: You need Secure Boot, some version of TPM , and DirectX 12.   Hard restrictions on TPM and age of CPU (less than 3 years) have been relaxed, but the machine has to be modestly compatible.

Comment: SetupDiag might tell you why the upgrade failed but if your system is incompatible you already know why that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm back to post my solution.

I've mentioned that I tried to install the WiFi driver for the "Broadcom
802.11ac Wi‑Fi wireless networking", to do it, I've used the file:

- Broadcom-FORCED-10x64-BCM43x_7.77.119.0-drp.

The installation was not so easy because I didn't have full access to the system, I did it by calling Control Panel from the command line. Unfortunately, even the installation was successful I'm not able to connect to my WiFi network, even trying by netsh command.

**The solution for this case is to use a USB to Ethernet Adapted**, in this case:

- Airlink101 USB 3.0 to Ethernet Gigabit Adapter (AGE-1000)

I've connected it directly to the router ethernet port and this device was detected by Windows 11 without any other driver installation.

After one or two reboots, Windows 11 was able to connect to the internet and concludes successfully its own installation.

Thank you all for your comments and edits.